# How to target a specific part of an array in an ordered list

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I target the last names to be red? In the HTML, I have an ID named `elements` and the same in CSS to make the last names red. I tried to do various things but I'm finding no success.

```
var names = ["Jane Doe", "Jose Munez", "John Williams"];
var splitNames = names.sort().reverse();

function anything(str1) {
    for (i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        str1[i] = str1[i].split(",").join(" ");
        return str1;
    }
}
console.log(anything(splitNames));

//getLastName : takes argument 'str', splits the string passed in after there's a space and retrieves all characters after the split (that's what the 1 means)
function getLastName(str) {
    return str.split(' ')[1];
}

function orderedList(listItem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
        var l = document.createElement('li');
        l.innerHTML = listItem[i];
        document.getElementById('elements').appendChild(l);
        console.log(getLastName(listItem[i]));
        var list = "";
    }
}

orderedList(splitNames);
```

Comment: Why not echo the last name into a div that has the CSS element applied? Can you show me an example of this on codepen, or the site you are working on? In the future provide more details.

Comment: Shouldn´t that `return` statement be outside the loop in your `anything` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split the names up into 2, first name and last name. Then I used a span element to enclose the last name. The span has a class, so I then applied CSS to the class:

```js
var names = ["Jane Doe", "Jose Munez", "John Williams"];
var splitNames = names.sort().reverse();

function anything(str1) {
  for (i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    str1[i] = str1[i].split(",").join(" ");
    return str1;
  }
}
console.log(anything(splitNames));

//getLastName : takes argument 'str', splits the string passed in after    there's a space and retrieves all characters after the split (that's what the 1 means)
function getLastName(str) {
  return str.split(' ')[1];
}

//New function just for convenience
function getFirstName(str) {
  return str.split(' ')[0];
}

function orderedList(listItem) {
  for (var i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
    var l = document.createElement('li');

    //Notice how the span class is used to enclose the last name
    l.innerHTML = getFirstName(listItem[i]) + " <span class=" + 'last-name' + ">" + getLastName(listItem[i]) + "</span>";

    document.getElementById('elements').appendChild(l);
    console.log(getLastName(listItem[i]));

    var list = "";
  }
}
orderedList(splitNames);
```

```css
.last-name {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="elements">

</ul>
```

I manipulated the `li`'s innerHTML to include a span with class `last-name`. Then I applied `color: red` to all `last-name`s.

Comment: Thanks so much! This has been giving me problems for the longest.

Comment: No problem @Damarco_W, if you've got any other problems I'll be glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
<style>
span.red-name {
    color : red;
}
</style>

<ul id="elements">
</ul>

<script>

var names = ["Jane Doe", "Jose Munez", "John Williams"];
var splitNames = names.sort().reverse();

function orderedList(listItem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
        var l = document.createElement('li');
        var flname = listItem[i].split(' ');
        l.innerHTML = flname[0] + ' <span class="red-name">'+flname[1] + '</span>';
        document.getElementById('elements').appendChild(l);
}

}
orderedList(splitNames);

</script>
```

Comment: Oops, the same answer as Andrew L.